# Update using join on big table - performance tips?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-performance, database-administration

Been struggling with this update, that never finishes

```
update votings v
set voter_id = (select pv.number from voters pv WHERE pv.person_id = v.person_id);
```

Table being currently has 96M records

```
select count(0) from votings;
  count   
----------
 96575239
(1 registro)
```

Update apparently is using index

```
explain update votings v                             
set voter_id = (select pv.number from voters pv WHERE pv.rl_person_id = v.person_id);
                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Update on votings v  (cost=0.00..788637465.40 rows=91339856 width=1671)
   ->  Seq Scan on votings v  (cost=0.00..788637465.40 rows=91339856 width=1671)
         SubPlan 1
           ->  Index Scan using idx_voter_rl_person_id on voters pv  (cost=0.56..8.58 rows=1 width=9)
                 Index Cond: (rl_person_id = v.person_id)
(5 registros)
```

Here are the indexes I have for votings

```
Índices:
    "votings_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "votings_election_id_voter_id_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (election_id, person_id)
    "votings_external_id_external_source_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (external_id, external_source)
    "idx_votings_updated_at" btree (updated_at DESC)
    "idx_votings_vote_party" btree (vote_party)
    "idx_votings_vote_state_vote_party" btree (vote_state, vote_party)
    "idx_votings_voter_id" btree (person_id)
Restrições de chave estrangeira:
    "votings_election_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (election_id) REFERENCES elections(id)
    "votings_voter_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES people_all(id)
```

Guys, any ideia who plays the biggest part on the update running slowly? the number of rows or the join being used?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: `count(0)` is actually slower than `count(*)` in Postgres (and there is no DBMS where `count(0)` is indeed faster)

Comment: good to know! usually I use (0) or (1) never though about it

Comment: You could try if `update votings v
  set voter_id = pf.number
from from voters pv 
WHERE pv.person_id = v.person_id;` is faster

Comment: from the explain, it really did improve, will try to execute it, thanks @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @horse_with_no_name, I'm struggling to understand this syntax: `update votings v   set voter_id = pf.number from from voters pv  WHERE pv.person_id = v.person_id;`. First, I guess the "pf.number" is a typo of "pv.number"; but beyond that, is the rest of this syntax actually correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating all the rows in the table is going to be really expensive.  I would suggest re-creating the table:

```
create temp_votings as
    select v.*, vv.vote_id
    from votings v join
         voters vv
         on vv.person_id = v.person_id;
```

For this query, you want an index on `votes(person_id, vote_id)`.  I am guessing that `person_id` might already be the primary key; if so, no additional index is needed.

Then, you can replace the existing table -- but back it up first:

```
truncate table votings;

insert into votings ( . . . )    -- list columns here
    select . . .                 -- and the same columns here
    from temp_votings;
```

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion I can make here would be to use a covering index for the subquery lookup:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_cover ON voters (person_id, number);
```

While in the context of a select this might not advantage much over your current index on `person_id` alone, in the context of an update it might matter more.  The reason is that for an update this index might relieve Postgres from having to create and maintain a copy of the original table in its state before the update.

Comment: That improved by half, taking it from the explain after I created the index, although, not using the subquery, improved it even more, thanks @Tim Biegeleisen

Answer (score 1):

If you actually have 91339856 rows in `voting`, the 91339856 index scans on `voters` are certainly the dominant cost factor. The sequential scan will be faster.

You can probably boost performance if you don't force PostgreSQL to do a nested loop join:

```
UPDATE votings
SET voter_id = voters.number
FROM voters
WHERE votings.person_id = voters.person_id;
```

Comment: I was able to run the query like this, it still took a long time though, but betten then it was. I guess re-creating the table in that case would be the ideal way for speed.

Comment: Yes, that may well be. Increasing `work_mem` could also help a little.